# Spring Reactive Programming with Webflux - multiple operations as a non-blocking stream

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

I have the following code:

```
public Flux<Offer> getAllFilteredOffers(Map<String, String> searchParams) {

    Flux<ProductProperties> productProperties = productPropertiesService.findProductPropertiesBySearchCriteria(searchParams);
    Flux<Product> products = productService.findProductsByPropertyId(productProperties);
    Flux<Product> productsByAvailability = productService.getAllProductsByAvailability(products, searchParams);
    Flux<Offer> offers = offerRepository.findByPropertiesIds(productsByAvailability);
    return offers;
```

This method:

```
productService.getAllProductsByAvailability(products, searchParams);
```

looks like:

```
public Flux<Product> getAllProductsByAvailability(Flux<Product> products,
            Map<String, String> searchParams) {
```

How to pass `List<Product>` to `getAllProductsByAvailability` to keep non-blocking operations?
I've read that map is blocking and should be avoided.
Maybe something like that?

```
    Flux
                    .just(productPropertiesService.findProductPropertiesBySearchCriteria(searchParams))
                    .flatMap(productProperties -> productService.findProductsByPropertyId(productProperties))
                    .flatMap(products -> productService.getAllProductsByAvailability(Flux.create(products)?????????, searchParams))
???
```

I'm not expert in Webflux, currently I'm trying to figure out how to handle problems like: I have Flux but in a second step I need to pull some data from the previous Flex<> object - keeping non-blocking stream.

Than you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you read about `map`, but if you look at the official documenation [Webflux map operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) there is nothing about blocking, it just uses synchronous function to each item.

Use this code:

```
productPropertiesService.findProductPropertiesBySearchCriteria(searchParams)
                .flatMap(productProperties -> productService.findProductsByPropertyId(productProperties))
                .collectList()   (1)
                .flatMapMany(products -> productService.getAllProductsByAvailability(Flux.fromIterable(products), searchParams)) (2)
```

1) collect all elements to List and convert to Mono>

2) create FLux from List and provide it as a parameter, flatMapMany transform Mono to Flux

Comment: Yauhen Balykin - it is a non-blocking operation as a whole?

Comment: Yes, operators are non-blocking, but if you afraid that any operation is blocking, you can read it on a official documenation.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's exactily what I've looked for